# How do I set a specific amplitude?

Tags: quantum-state

Is it possible in IBM quantum composer to set specific values for the amplitudes of a certain qubit, say alpha = 0.8 and beta = 0.6 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use RY-gate for this task.
$$\begin{align}\begin{aligned}\newcommand{\th}{\frac{\theta}{2}}\\\begin{split}RY(\theta) = \exp\left(-i \th Y\right) =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos{\th} & -\sin{\th} \\
        \sin{\th} & \cos{\th}
    \end{pmatrix}\end{split}\end{aligned}\end{align}$$
You just need to get the angle $\theta$ such that alpha = 0.8 = $\cos(\theta/2)$

So, $\theta = 2\arccos(0.8) = 1.28700222$

[image]

Comment: Does it change something if you use RX or RZ gate instead ?